# Thymeleaf - Insert HTML into <p>

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have the following Java variables:

```
context.setVariable("content", "test &lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;");
context.setVariable("condition", condition);
```

and I want to place this into the following template:

```
<p th:text="${condition}?${content}:''"></p>
```

The **expected result** is: "test **test**" if the condition is true. However, 
the result is

```
"test &lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;"
```

if I open my page and the condition is true. Changing `th:text=...` to `th:utext=...` results in

```
"test <b>test</b>"
```

displayed on my page, which is still not what I want.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the actual HTML, then you need to pass actual (not escaped) HTML and use `th:utext`.  (It doesn't make sense to pass in escaped HTML and think Thymeleaf will unescape it for you.)

```
// Controller
context.setVariable("content", "test <br>test</br>");

<!-- HTML -->
<p th:utext="${condition}?${content}:''"></p>
```

If you really do want to pass in `"test &lt;br&gt;test&lt;/br&gt;"`, then you're going to have to use string search/replace to change those characters back into `<` and `>` (probably using the [`#strings`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#strings) utility object).

Comment: This is strange, because inserting escaped HTML directly `<p th:utext="${condition}?'test &lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;':''"></p>` works like a charm. Additionally, your provided code is working as well. Nevertheless, if I try to replace the escaped < and > from my code with #strings.replace, I get a XML parsing exception that th:utext must not contain the '<' character. Can you please elaborate on that?